# Complexity of Constructing the Clique Complex of the graph

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, simplicial-complex

The Clique Complex is a way of constructing a simplicial complex out of a graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex).

Basically, it is formed by the sets of vertices in the cliques of the graph $G$.

Given that finding even one maximum clique in a graph is hard (so called NP-complete) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), I would expect that the complexity of constructing the clique complex should be non-polynomial? Since the construction of the Clique Complex requires finding all cliques, which surely is harder than finding the maximum clique?

However I don't find any references calculating the complexity (time complexity). Computational complexity I would suppose it is clearly NP-hard. Is there any references or estimate of the complexity? Just any rough estimate would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We certainly need exponential time (in the number of vertices) to construct the clique complex, since the clique complex has exponential size in the number of vertices ([more precisely, there are $n$-vertex graphs with $3^{n/3}$ maximal cliques](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8390/the-number-of-cliques-in-a-graph-the-moon-and-moser-1965-result)). And we can definitely do it in exponential time, since the trivial algorithm of "check if each set is a clique" is just $O(n^2 \cdot 2^n)$.

In practice, I don't think we mainly bother *computing* the clique complex in any real sense. We just think of the graph itself as being a structure which can answer queries such as "is $\sigma$ a face of $\operatorname{Cl}(G)$?" or "given a $k$-dimensional face $\sigma$, what are the $(k+1)$-dimensional faces containing it?" in polynomial time ($O(k^2)$ and $O(n)$ respectively).

Whether this is good enough or not really depends on what you want to compute. If you want the $k^{\text{th}}$ homology of $\operatorname{Cl}(G)$, for fixed $k$, then the number of relevant cliques is polynomial in $n$, and in fact the homology can be computed in polynomial time. On the other hand, if you are given any simplicial complex $L$ as input, together with the integer $k$, deciding if $H_k(L) = 0$ is already NP-hard. So it shouldn't bother us too much if figuring out $\operatorname{Cl}(G)$ is hard too. (See [these slides on homology and complexity](http://www.icms.org.uk/downloads/ATMCS5/Adamaszek.pdf) for these results and more.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. However in the slides you mentioned, they say deciding if $H_k(Cl(G)=0$ is NP-hard? Doesn’t this contradict “in fact the homology can be computed in polynomial time”?

Comment: A subtlety. The algorithm is $n^{O(k)}$, which is polynomial for fixed $k$. But if $k$ is part of your input, then it's not polynomial anymore.

Comment: By the way is there any reference (paper or book) that elaborates how people don't "bother computing the clique complex in any real sense"? I am interested to learn more, but I am an outsider to this field, I don't know where to start.

Comment: It's not my field either, so maybe it was irresponsible of me to make such sweeping claims. I don't know of any citation worthy of being called a *reference* on the matter. But [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1811004) is at least an *example*.